# Springboot application jar - very slow view resolver

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot, visualvm

We have a springboot application.
When we run it in eclipse it runs fine, but when we build a jar, the performance degrades drastically.

The visualvm dump shows that `processDespatch` method takes a lot of time. See attached snapshot.

Upon further analysis we found that the ViewResolver class gets into a lot of high amount of processing, just trying to resolve the view.

[image: Visual VM Call Tree]

Process Dispatch in the fat jar takes whopping 10.5 seconds. While same happens within 0.5 seconds in Eclipse.

Therefore Eclipse must be doing something related to resolving View Resolution very quickly, (probably finding the correct class).

Has anyone faced this issue or know how we can do the same quickly in the fat jar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the fact that the embedded tomcat was running in developer mode.

It was taking a lot of time to compile the JSP.

This is the related spring issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2825